# Thunderbird 102.13.0 (Ubuntu) is sending out empty e-mails

Tags: ubuntu, thunderbird, exchange, thunderbird-addon

I use Thunderbird with an MS Exchange server and the Exquilla for Exchange add-on.

It worked reasonably well until yesterday (not perfectly, but reasonably well). I restarted Thunderbird yesterday after a surprise freeze, and now it only sends e-mails with no contents.

Interestingly, the drafts are saved correctly, also on the Exchange server.

Disabling all plugins (except for the Exquilla) did not help.

Upgrading from 102.12.0 to 102.13.0 did not help, either.

Google returns a few hits to this problem from the past two decades, but none of the solutions seem to be applicable.

I don't know even where I should start with this issue. OWA is not a usable solution, Evolution does not properly integrate the calendars with Exchange (last time I checked). Most importantly, Evolution does not appear to have this automatic archive feature (hit a key and it moves the message to folder year/month), not to mention some other issues with searching.

Comment: From your issue description and other comments below which about the similar problem, seems it's likely to be related to the exquilla plugin. Have you tried disabling the add-in temporarily and see if it works?

Comment: Without the add-in, I cannot log to my e-mail account. I know that I could spend more time on debugging this issue, but this is one of my main tools and I could not afford to loose it. Therefore, I switched to evolution for now. With my question, I was hoping that someone else already solved the problem.

Comment: You can check the answer below edited by robot144 2 days ago. He worked the issue around by installing an earlier version of the add-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ExQuilla add-on has been updated yesterday. Installing the updated add-on resolves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem on ubuntu 22.04LTS with thunderbird 1:102.13.0
Reconnecting the account did not work. It stopped working with the upgrade of the exquilla plugin to 115.0 yesterday, July 11 2023.

**I can work around the issue for now by manually installing the previous version of the plugin** from https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/exquilla-exchange-web-services/versions/ . I needed to switch off the automatic updating, too.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: There are numerous reports of the add-on breaking since the 115 release of Thunderbird: https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/exquilla-exchange-web-services/ ; I'd say the best course of action is to reach out to the developer about the problem.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the addon?

Comment: Dear Preston. Note, that I am not using thunderbird version 115 but 102.13.0. It's more likely that the update of the exquilla plugin is the cause of the problem. I did reach out to the developer. I have no solution at the moment and just wanted to confirm that this combination can have issues.